# Customizing errors from Query extractor in Rust with Axum

Tags: rust, rust-axum

I have followed the example provided [here](https://github.com/tokio-rs/axum/blob/main/examples/customize-extractor-error/src/derive_from_request.rs) to customize the extractor error for the `Json` extractor:

```rust
#[derive(FromRequest)]
#[from_request(via(axum::Json), rejection(ApiError))]
pub struct JsonExtractor<T>(pub T);

#[axum::debug_handler]
pub(crate) async fn create(
    state: State<AppState>,
    JsonExtractor(json): JsonExtractor<RouteBody>,
) -> Result<axum::Json<Customer>, ApiError>
```

This works great, but when I try the same for extracting from the Query, I get errors:

```rust
#[derive(FromRequest)]
#[from_request(via(axum::extract::Query), rejection(ApiError))]
pub struct QueryExtractor<T>(pub T);

#[axum::debug_handler]
pub(crate) async fn list(
    state: State<AppState>,
    query: QueryExtractor<RouteQuery>, // errors here
) -> Result<axum::Json<List<Customer>>, ApiError>
```

```
the trait bound `QueryExtractor<customers::list::RouteQuery>: FromRequest<AppState, hyper::Body, _>` is not satisfied
Function argument is not a valid axum extractor.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference is [`Json` implements `FromRequest`](https://docs.rs/axum/latest/axum/struct.Json.html#impl-FromRequest%3CS,+B,+ViaRequest%3E-for-Json%3CT%3E) while [`Query` implements `FromRequestParts`](https://docs.rs/axum/latest/axum/extract/struct.Query.html#impl-FromRequestParts%3CS%3E-for-Query%3CT%3E) (the latter doesn't consume the request body).

So you'd use [`#[derive(FromRequestParts)`](https://docs.rs/axum/latest/axum/extract/derive.FromRequestParts.html) instead:

> This works similarly to `#[derive(FromRequest)]` except it uses `FromRequestParts`. All the same options are supported.